# Excel file into SSAS cube

Tags: excel, ssis, ssas

What is the easiest way to get data from Excel file into a cube in SSAS?

I got an excel file with 4 tables and I want to build a cube with that data.
Is the only way to build a SSIS package moving the excel file to my DB and then connect to my DB with SSAS, or is there a faster/easier way?

(Not interested in performance since its only 10 000 rows of data.)

Answer (score 0):

Not required. You may choose you excel spreadsheet as a source to ingest data.

Read this: [data sources for SSAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/tabular-models/data-sources-supported-ssas-tabular)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but isn't that just for tabular, not for a multidimensional cube?

Comment: That's right. Unfortunately, ODBC connections to file's (Excel, delimited) is not supported and hence you may consider staging them on SQL Server tables or likewise and later use these tables as sources.